# Determine the order of a group by its presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G := <a,b \ \big\vert \ a,bb>$ be the presentation of a group. What can be said about the order of $G$?

My first thought would be 2, and that G consists of two elements, $a = e_G$ and $b$. But does this notation rule $a = b$, and so $\# G = 1, G = \{a = b = e_G\}$, out? Is there a definitive answer?

Comment: You can drop $a$ from the notation, i.e., $G=\langle b \mid b^2=1\rangle=C_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group described by a presentation is, in some sense, the most general or *most free* group that satisfies the required relations: Only the relations which are forced to hold in *any* group satisfying the given relations hold in the presented group.

Hence, $a=b$ is excluded (since there *is* a group over $a$ and $b$ in which $b^2=a=e$ but $a\neq b$); therefore $G=\{a,b\}\cong(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,+)$ and $\lvert G\rvert=2$.